What is this contruction material called, please?
Replacing basement baseboards with pvc as recent rains led to a backup that didn't touch the walls but someday might. Anyway, I came across these hard ?rubber?  Strips at thr bottom of the existing walls. Does anyone know what this is called so I can replace it? Staff at both lowes and home depot were stumped.

Please complete this question by adding a photo.

Picture would help.  Unless the strips are sealed to the floor and go up the wall, they might only protect the bottom wood plate from moisture from the cement/concrete.  Water might stain baseboard, but drywall does not like wet.

Vinyl covebase / baseboard, maybe?

Yeah, sounds like the vinyl typically used in commercial property.
